# What are laws regarding corruption in China, and how effective are they?

Tags: china

I'm wondering how effective the government is at keeping corruption to a minimum, the laws regarding corruption, and how corruptible the police are. I'm fine with either information on a specific province or overall information. Any amount of information on any of the questions is fine, I'm just curious. I'm not really looking for a "one answer covers it all" type of thing, probably small contributions from people who happen to know a thing or two or are willing to spend some time doing research. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to History.Stackexchange.

Comment: Do you plan to bribe the police?

Comment: This would be a better fit in travel.SE

Comment: Haha. @Anixx I do not plan to bribe the police, I'm just wondering about the local culture etc.

Comment: @canadiancreed Why? Is the history SE not for local and recent politics as well?

Comment: @ReliableSource. The FAQ wasn't very clear, but it did have the line "Factual current political history questions" in the "is about" section, however, I think what throws people off is the fact that you've put, "I will be traveling there soon," in your question.

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit; I'm not going to flag the question in the hope that we can edit it to something useful.  There are too many questions, they are too vague, and I can't imagine how a good answer could be based on facts.